# finding point of convergence for Fourier sine series

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I have a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1-x$. I have found its Fourier sine series to be $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} b_n \sin(n\pi x)$ with $b_n = \dfrac{2(1-x)}{n\pi}(1-\cos(n\pi))$. Now the question ask for what value $-1\leq x \leq 1$ does the Fourier sine series converge to $f(x)$.

I have tried to play around with $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} b_n \sin(n\pi x)$ and get: 
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{2(1-x)}{n\pi}(1-\cos(n\pi)) \sin(n\pi x) = \sum^{\infty}_{\substack{n=1,\\ n\text{ odd}}} \dfrac{2(1-x)}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi x)\\&= f(x)\sum^{\infty}_{\substack{n=1,\\ n\text{ odd}}} \frac{2}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi x).
\end{align} 
Now I'm trying to figure out the $x$ value that make $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1,\text{ n odd}} \dfrac{2}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi x)$ to be $1$. Am I doing using the right approach? If so, how should I go from here? If not, what are some suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Converges for $-1<x<1$ to $f(x)$. For $x\in \{0, 1\}$ it converges to $(f(0)+f(1))/2 = 1/2$.

Comment: Just look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions). Function is of bounded variation if for example it has a bounded derivative.

Comment: $b_n$ aren't supposed to depend on $x$.

Comment: @metamorphy but for fourier sine series isn't $b_n$ depend on f(x) and hence x?

Comment: @Jakobian Sorry if this is too basic to ask: what is the relation between fourier series and fourier sine/cosine series for a particular function f?(I'm assuming not addition but more like either representing f with only sine or cosine or sum of both) Asking because here "Dirichlet's theorem says in particular that under the Dirichlet conditions the Fourier series for f converges and is equal to f wherever f is continuous". So does it still work if I substitute "fourier series" with fourier sine or fourier cos series?

Comment: @jessiewithie it converges to the odd/even part. Any function $f$ can be uniquely expressed as $f = g+h$, $g$ is odd, $h$ is even, $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$, $h(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$. And yes, $b_n$ is a coefficient so it shouldn't depend on $x$. It depends on the function $f$, not on $f(x)$ for some random $x\in[0, 1]$.